# UV Editor Selection Glow

Tags: uv-image-editor

In Blender 2.9 when selecting multiple edges in the UV Editor is there any way to turn off or reduce the glow effect on neighboring edges?

[image]

I've been having trouble manually converting some models from tris to quads via the UV map because the glow(?) makes it very difficult to tell which edges have been actually selected. I told a friend about this issue and he was having no such problems - as he still uses 2.83 which doesn't have this glow effect.

Please, if anyone has any suggestions / insight into this I would greatly appreciate it - thank you!

[image]

(Both images I'm using edge select mode with UV sync and selected only the diagonal edges I would want to dissolve)